# Programatically access currently-selected XML Map in Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto

I'm developing an Excel AddIn that needs to know what the currently selected XML Map is in the XML Source Pane.

I haven't found any way to access it.
I've been digging in the docs for the [Microsoft Office Tools for Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Workbook.aspx) and haven't find anything saying it's impossible.

Anybody has gotten into it?